# Bounty not received after grace period despite satisfying auto-award conditions

Tags: support, bounties, expired-bounty

[Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/506564/what-is-the-probability-of-a-photon-being-emitted-by-the-sun-actually-being-abso/506972#506972) a bounty of 50 points was announced, and the grace period has already ended. Although I had a score of 3 upvotes and the answear was also accepted, the infobox says that the reward has not been given since *"This question has not received enough attention."* Shouldn't the highest score over 2 upvotes get the bounty? Not that the 50 points mean so much to me, but why is this?

Comment: "*This question has not received enough attention.*" was there for 7 days I believe. It is not the reason of not giving bounty.

Comment: ok in this case it is a delay of the system, according to the related question, thanks